# HTML checkformvalidity returning true when input field is empty and pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,8}"

Tags: javascript, html

JS's checkFormValidity() function is returning true for an empty input field even though patter attribute in HTML mentions pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,10}"

HTML:

```
<div class="name deets">
    <label for="idname" class="label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="idname" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,25}">
</div>
```

JS:

```
if (form.checkValidity()) {
            console.log('true')
            change();
        }
        else {
            console.log('false')
            form.reportValidity();

        }
}
```

returns true

I currently dont want to use the "required" attribute,
since i am doing an animation in css, if the user enters an invalid input type and having the requied tag causes the animation to begin along with page load.

Comment: And what about missing `required` property ?

Comment: @MisterJojo thank you for your response, I currently dont want to use the "required" attribute, since i am doing an animation in css, if the user enters an invalid input type and having the requied tag causes the animation to begin along with page load.

Comment: An empty non-required field is valid though, so you need to validate manually.